# MapStruct record to record mapping does not work

Tags: java, mapstruct, java-17, java-record

I try to convert a Java record from one package to another.

```java
@Mapper
public interface KriteriumMapper {

    KriteriumMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(KriteriumMapper.class);
    de.model.Kriterium fromPersistenceRecord(Kriterium k);
}
```

```java
package de.persistence.model.nontransactional;

public record Kriterium(String name, String crkSpaltenname) {}
```

To

```java
package de.model;

public record Kriterium(String name, String crkSpaltenname) {}
```

But Mapstruct creates a mapper with an empty constructor for the new record, which is obviously not possible:

```java
@Override
public de.Kriterium fromPersistenceRecord(de.persistence.model.Kriterium k) {
    if ( k == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    
    de.model.Kriterium kriterium = new de.Kriterium();
    
    return kriterium;
}
```

The Mapstruct version is `1.5.5.Final`.

How to handle Java record-to-record mapping?

I'm expecting a mapper implementation with uses the regular all args constructor of a jave record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix-up the package names, I have noticed you use more than 2 `Kriterium` classes:

- `de.persistence.model.nontransactional.Kriterium`
- `de.persistence.model.Kriterium`
- `de.Kriterium`

You want to double-check that the classes from the correct packages are used in the `KriteriumMapper`.

Don't forget to compile with the [`-parameters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html) flag to enable generating metadata for reflection on method parameters (thanks to [Rob Spoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180351/rob-spoor)).

Here is a minimum working sample of record-to-record mapping:

```java
@Mapper
public interface KriteriumMapper {

    Kriterium2 fromPersistenceRecord(Kriterium k);
}

public record Kriterium(String name, String crkSpaltenname) {}

public record Kriterium2(String name, String crkSpaltenname) {}
```

Here is the generated implementation of `KriteriumMapperImpl` after compilation :

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-10-02T18:18:30+0700",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 17.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
public class KriteriumMapperImpl implementsKriteriumMapper {

    @Override
    public Kriterium2 fromPersistenceRecord(Kriterium k) {
        if ( k == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String name = null;
        String crkSpaltenname = null;

        name = k.name();
        crkSpaltenname = k.crkSpaltenname();

        Kriterium2 kriterium2 = new Kriterium2( name, crkSpaltenname );

        return kriterium2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the `-parameters` compiler flag? Because if not then I wonder how MapStruct will map `name` to `name`, and not `name` to `crkSpaltenname`. And perhaps Andreas is missing the `-parameters` flag, and that is the actual solution to his issue.

Comment: Nikolas sorry, the three package names was a fault while editing the question. I yust want to remove our company name from package name.
Thank You to investigate and show me that it's posible to get this working!

Rob You are right. I was missing the -parametes flag!

Comment: @AndreasSchouten glad to be of help

Comment: @RobSpoor you don’t need to specify `-parameters` for the canonical constructor of a record type. Compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67048729/2711488)